# Android app Crash

Tags: android

Why is this:

```
    public class HelpTab extends Activity
    {
LinearLayout helpLayout; //was changed to LinearLayout helpLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
TextView helpText = new TextView(this);
Button tips = new Button(this);
Button walkThrough = new Button(this);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    buttonCreator();
    setContentView(helpLayout);
}

public void buttonCreator()
{
         //Button featuress defined in here (setText("") and adding them to the layout, addView();)
    }
```

Causing my program to crash? 
I have looked at the code extensively and I can't put my finger on it, and the debugger also says source not found when it opens the new page tab thing to tell me what is happening.

Comment: Full log trace output required please.

Comment: Is your Activity properly declared in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: If you post the Logcat it would be much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `setContentView(helpLayout);` first and then  `buttonCreator();`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(helpLayout);
   buttonCreator();
}
```

Assuming that you are trying to initialize your button inside buttonCreater() with respect to a button you have declared in your `helplayout`, you might run into Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Yes I just saw that, but why is it getting a null exception? should it not work correctly as the buttons have not been added to the main layout yet, hence the reason for the method in the first place. I think I understand where to go form here, just fully define the button e.g. Button newButton = new Button(this); whatever at the top of the class file.

Comment: Only when u provide the contentView to your Activity, android will know as of where to find the elements(which xml res). if not it will throw u null Pointer .

Comment: I am not getting an InvocationTargetException. I will add the top half of my code now.

Comment: But what's the point of giving android the ContentView() before anything is even stored in the view, let alone the view being initiated. Which is why I had left it after to give time for the buttons to be created, therefore I don't have to run invalidate to get a refresh of the screen? This coding is strictly Java there is next to no XML editing unless its crucial.

Comment: Becasue it is a reference, whether it has anything in it or not.  Until  you set it you cannot attach anything to it because it doesn't exist as far as the framework is concerned.  It's like telling people to get on a boat that isn't at the dock yet...it can't happen.

Comment: Initializing an object creates it, is that not correct? Therefore the layout does not specifically need to be presented anywhere which is what the SetContext() is (unless I am wrong). So an instance of Button can be added to the layout, but since the layout is not the context it is only not visible. If I am wrong, which I may be, then how do you SetContext() if you have three views nested in each other, do you SetContext(Parent); or for each child too?